# DMZ Disk Space report

Tags: powershell

This PowerShell script is very useful, if you have SQL servers in the DMZ you can use this to get the total capacity, used capacity, free space and free space%. I use the same script to check the hard drive space for all my internal SQL servers.  However when I try to run this against my SQL servers in the DMZ a strange thing happens.

This PowerShell script gets the lists of SQL server from a file called dmzsl.txt. When I update the dmzsl.txt file with only one SQL server and run the PowerShell script I get 3 result sets back for the same server.

I have tried several methods to resolve this but I just can't get it to report back with one one data set without repeating.

[image]

```
set-location C:\SQLServerDiskSpaceReport

$isodate=Get-Date -format s
$isodate=$isodate -replace(":","")
$basepath=(Get-Location -PSProvider FileSystem).ProviderPath

$instancepath=$basepath + "\config\dmzsl.txt"
$outputfile="\DMZServerLogs\sql_server_db_sizes_" + $isodate + ".html"
$outputfilefull = $basepath + $outputfile

$filePath = ""

$freeSpaceFileName = $outputfilefull
$warning = 30
$critical = 10
New-Item -ItemType file $freeSpaceFileName -Force

Function writeHtmlHeader {
  param($fileName)

  $date = ( get-date ).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')
  Add-Content $fileName "<html>"
  Add-Content $fileName "<head>"
  Add-Content $fileName "<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'>"
  Add-Content $fileName '<title>DiskSpace Report</title>'
  add-content $fileName '<STYLE TYPE="text/css">'
  add-content $fileName  "<!--"
  add-content $fileName  "td {"
  add-content $fileName  "font-family: Tahoma;"
  add-content $fileName  "font-size: 11px;"
  add-content $fileName  "border-top: 1px solid #999999;"
  add-content $fileName  "border-right: 1px solid #999999;"
  add-content $fileName  "border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;"
  add-content $fileName  "border-left: 1px solid #999999;"
  add-content $fileName  "padding-top: 0px;"
  add-content $fileName  "padding-right: 0px;"
  add-content $fileName  "padding-bottom: 0px;"
  add-content $fileName  "padding-left: 0px;"
  add-content $fileName  "}"
  add-content $fileName  "body {"
  add-content $fileName  "margin-left: 5px;"
  add-content $fileName  "margin-top: 5px;"
  add-content $fileName  "margin-right: 0px;"
  add-content $fileName  "margin-bottom: 10px;"
  add-content $fileName  ""
  add-content $fileName  "table {"
  add-content $fileName  "border: thin solid #000000;"
  add-content $fileName  "}"
  add-content $fileName  "-->"
  add-content $fileName  "</style>"
  Add-Content $fileName "</head>"
  Add-Content $fileName "<body>"
  add-content $fileName  "<table width='100%'>"
  add-content $fileName  "<tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>"
  add-content $fileName  "<td colspan='7' height='25' align='center'>"
  add-content $fileName  "<font face='tahoma' color='#003399' size='4'><strong>DMZ SQL Server Disk Space Report - $date</strong></font>"
  add-content $fileName  "</td>"
  add-content $fileName  "</tr>"
  add-content $fileName  "</table>"
}

# Function to write the HTML Header to the file
Function writeTableHeader {
  param($fileName)

  Add-Content $fileName "<tr bgcolor=#CCCCCC>"
  Add-Content $fileName "<td width='10%' align='center'>Drive</td>"
  Add-Content $fileName "<td width='50%' align='center'>Drive Label</td>"
  Add-Content $fileName "<td width='10%' align='center'>Total Capacity(GB)</td>"
  Add-Content $fileName "<td width='10%' align='center'>Used Capacity(GB)</td>"
  Add-Content $fileName "<td width='10%' align='center'>Free Space(GB)</td>"
  Add-Content $fileName "<td width='10%' align='center'>Freespace %</td>"
  Add-Content $fileName "</tr>"
}

Function writeHtmlFooter {
  param($fileName)

  Add-Content $fileName "</body>"
  Add-Content $fileName "</html>"
}

Function writeDiskInfo {
  param($fileName,$devId,$volName,$frSpace,$totSpace)

  $totSpace=[math]::Round(($totSpace/1073741824),2)
  $frSpace=[Math]::Round(($frSpace/1073741824),2)
  $usedSpace = $totSpace - $frspace
  $usedSpace=[Math]::Round($usedSpace,2)
  $freePercent = ($frspace/$totSpace)*100
  $freePercent = [Math]::Round($freePercent,0)
  if ($freePercent -gt $warning) {
    Add-Content $fileName "<tr>"
    Add-Content $fileName "<td>$devid</td>"
    Add-Content $fileName "<td>$volName</td>"

    Add-Content $fileName "<td>$totSpace</td>"
    Add-Content $fileName "<td>$usedSpace</td>"
    Add-Content $fileName "<td>$frSpace</td>"
    Add-Content $fileName "<td>$freePercent</td>"
    Add-Content $fileName "</tr>"
  } elseif ($freePercent -le $critical) {
    Add-Content $fileName "<tr>"
    Add-Content $fileName "<td>$devid</td>"
    Add-Content $fileName "<td>$volName</td>"
    Add-Content $fileName "<td>$totSpace</td>"
    Add-Content $fileName "<td>$usedSpace</td>"
    Add-Content $fileName "<td>$frSpace</td>"
    Add-Content $fileName "<td bgcolor='#e60000' align=center>$freePercent</td>"
    #<td bgcolor='#e60000' align=center>
    Add-Content $fileName "</tr>"
  } else {
    Add-Content $fileName "<tr>"
    Add-Content $fileName "<td>$devid</td>"
    Add-Content $fileName "<td>$volName</td>"
    Add-Content $fileName "<td>$totSpace</td>"
    Add-Content $fileName "<td>$usedSpace</td>"
    Add-Content $fileName "<td>$frSpace</td>"
    Add-Content $fileName "<td bgcolor='#ffff00' align=center>$freePercent</td>"
    # #ffff00
    Add-Content $fileName "</tr>"
  }
}

writeHtmlHeader $freeSpaceFileName
foreach ($server in Get-Content $instancepath) {
  Add-Content $freeSpaceFileName "<table width='100%'><tbody>"
  Add-Content $freeSpaceFileName "<tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>"
  Add-Content $freeSpaceFileName "<td width='100%' align='center' colSpan=6><font face='tahoma' color='#003399' size='2'><strong> $server </strong></font></td>"
  Add-Content $freeSpaceFileName "</tr>"

  writeTableHeader $freeSpaceFileName

  $dp = Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -ComputerName $server |  Where-Object {$_.drivetype -eq 3}
  foreach ($item in $dp) {
    Write-Host  $item.DeviceID  $item.VolumeName $item.FreeSpace $item.Size
    writeDiskInfo $freeSpaceFileName $item.DeviceID $item.VolumeName $item.FreeSpace $item.Size
  }
}

$Command1 = "C:\SQLServerDiskSpaceReport\DMZServerLogs\sql_server_db_sizes_"
$Command2 = $isodate + ".html"
$Command3 = $Command1 +$Command2
Invoke-Expression $Command3
```

I do get one error message, but I am not proficient in PowerShell to know enough about this error. The error is also a little ambiguous as you can see it says it cannot validate argument on parameter 'computername'. However it was able to generate the report 3 time for the same server.

```
Get-WmiObject : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ComputerName'. The
argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty,
and then try the command again.
At C:\SQLServerDiskSpaceReport\DMZ Disk Space Report V3.ps1:155 char:54
+  $dp = Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -ComputerName $server |  Where-Object {$_ ...
+                                                      ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is actually rather self-explanatory. Your loop variable `$server` is empty. Check the content of the file `$instancepath`.

Comment: Yes, however why would it report empty when the script was able to return  information on the server?  Keep in mind that there is only one server listed in the dmzsl.txt file and it manages to repeat the same information three times.

Comment: @user36578 Without knowing the contents of `$instancepath` my guess would be that you have a blank line in the file.

Comment: Addendum: The error appears to occur in the third iteration. The values in that group are retained from the second iteration.

Comment: I do not believe that is the problem and here is why.  You see when I change the dmzsl.txt to instances.txt this script works.  The difference between the two files are as follow, the dmzsl.txt has a list of SQL server in the DMZ.  The instances.txt file has a list of SQL servers in the trusted network.  However for my testing I only have one SQL server listed in the dmzsl.txt file.  This lead me to think what if I were to use a new server list file?  So I created a new one called SL.txt and entered a few DMZ SQL servers. Well guess what, the script worked!

Comment: So, it appears that there is something wrong with the dmzsl.txt file which was causing the issue. The script runs great when I use server names but has a problem when I use the IP address. I need to do some more digging why this is the case.